# StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.dll!StackExchange.Redis.SocketManager.WriteAllQueues()

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

In our webapi code we use SignalR and redis backplane. I'm see the problem where our code hangs after sometime.

> StackExchange.Redis.StrongName.dll!StackExchange.Redis.SocketManager.WriteAllQueues() Line 288

Actually the code for caching the data works (I can see data getting populated in redis server) but after couple web request/response the code hangs. I've installed the latest package 'StackExchange.Redis 1.1.608'. Unfortunately in VS I don't see my code in stack when I hit break-all.

Any ideas what might be wrong or where to look for the problem. I wish I could put more details here but this is all I got. Thanks!

here is the snapshot of threads when I hit break-all in VS
[Threads]:

[image: Threads]

Comment: Same here. I've just checked our memory dump and detect the same issue. As a workaround, I'll release the connection and recreate it. I am gonna check it better, though.

Answer (score 1):

Those are threads [created by the StackExchange.Redis library](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/1.2.6/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/SocketManager.cs#L139-L147) to read and write to the socket connected to Redis.

It is normal for the writer thread to be be blocked inside [`WriteAllQueues()`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/1.2.6/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/SocketManager.cs#L402) because it is calling [`Monitor.Wait()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.wait?view=netframework-4.7.2). The thread will awaken when there is work to do.

The read thread probably blocks on reading from the socket, but I can't find in the source code where this happens.